# Accessing error object in response from API Slice redux toolit

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have this slice

```
 ...
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
        baseUrl: BASE_ENDPOINT,
        prepareHeaders: headers => {
            const token = Cookies.get(TOKEN_COOKIE)
            if (token) headers.set('authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
            return headers;
        },
    }),
    getUserData: builder.query<SomeProps, void>({
        query: () => ({
            url: "...",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        }),
...
```

At one point in this

```
const {
    data,
    isLoading,
    error
} = useGetUserInfoQuery()
```

`error` becomes true and contains this

```
{"status":500,"data":{"status":"FAILED","message":"Some message I want to display."}}
```

However, the TypeScript compiler complains about this

```
error.data.message
```

It says

> Property  data  does not exist on type  FetchBaseQueryError | SerializedError 
> Property  data  does not exist on type  SerializedError

I cannot even do this

error!!.data!!.message!!

How would I access `data.message` in `error`?

Comment: `error!` doesn't help because it's not telling you it could be null/undefined, it's telling you it could be one of two kinds of thing. Have you considered [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) to (presumably) `FetchBaseQueryError`? Actual [mre]: https://tsplay.dev/N9az3N.

Answer (score 0):

The `error` type is `unknown`, so you'll need to cast it to an appropriate type if you would like to access specific properties.

See [useQuery](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#usequery) hook declarations:

> ```
> type UseQuery = (
>   arg: any | SkipToken,
>   options?: UseQueryOptions,
> ) => UseQueryResult
>
> type UseQueryResult<T> = {
>   // Base query state
>   originalArgs?: unknown // Arguments passed to the query
>   data?: T // The latest returned result regardless of hook arg, if present
>   currentData?: T // The latest returned result for the current hook arg, if present
>   error?: unknown // Error result if present
>   requestId?: string // A string generated by RTK Query
>   endpointName?: string // The name of the given endpoint for the query
>   startedTimeStamp?: number // Timestamp for when the query was initiated
>   fulfilledTimeStamp?: number // Timestamp for when the query was completed
>
>   // Derived request status booleans
>   isUninitialized: boolean // Query has not started yet.
>   isLoading: boolean // Query is currently loading for the first time. No data yet.
>   isFetching: boolean // Query is currently fetching, but might have data from an earlier request.
>   isSuccess: boolean // Query has data from a successful load.
>   isError: boolean // Query is currently in an "error" state.
>
>   refetch: () => QueryActionCreatorResult // A function to force refetch the query - returns a Promise with additional methods
> }
> ```

Example usage:

```js
interface MyError {
  status: number;
  data: {
    status: string;
    message: string;
  };
}
```

```js
const {
  data,
  isLoading,
  error
} = useGetUserInfoQuery();

...

(error as MyError).data.message;
```